# Need help filtering IP Address within a listview C#

Tags: c#, listview, filter

Try to keep it short, I am making a c# admin panel for a friends game he's working on, but we want it not to display any admin IP address. This what we got right now. But the issue I am having it showing that every IP is whitelisted. I must be doing something really dumb but I can't figure it, any advice that be great, thank you.

```
    byte[] whiteList = this.webClient.DownloadData(this.whiteList);
    Turtle_IP turtle = Util.GetGameIPs(RPC, IPGames, x);
    if (turtle.TurtleIPAddress != "0.0.0.0" && turtle.isValid)
    { 
        if (turtle.TurtleName.Contains(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(whiteList)))
        {
            turtle.TurtleIPAddress = "Whitelisted";
        }
        IpListBox.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(turtle.TurtleName)
        {
            SubItems =
            {
                turtle.TurtleIPAddress,
                GetWord(RPC.xbc, address + 0x00000080).ToString(),
                LevelIcon,
                nat.ToString()
            }
        });
     }
}
break;
```

Comment: You probably want to check whether the `turtle.TurtleIPAdress` contains (or is) is the `whiteList` instead of checking the `turtle.TurtleName`